# How to enable error reporting for wp admin section

Tags: editor

I have updating my wordpress version to latest version after updating it locally.When i try to edit a page the page crashed and not working after editing and save.I have enable the errors but if show error log when i try to load front end not for the wp admin section.Is there any way so i enable or give permission to admin section to generate error reporting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the error log of the server which is running wordpress. I use nginx to run wordpress on an ubuntu system. Therefore the log is located in /var/log/nginx/error.log. I run the following terminal command to view the error log while opening the wordpress site in the browser.

```
tail -f -n 0 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Depending on your operating system and server software (Apache, NGINX, XAMPP, WAMP) you should google how to view the server logs.

Comment: I am working on localhost.wamp

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771241/wamp-how-to-show-warning-messages-in-browser is of help for you.
Or this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713001/where-can-i-find-the-wamp-error-log .